# Firebase image upload error object Object

Tags: firebase, ionic2, firebase-storage

I am attempting to upload a image to firebase database but always getting this error. Need help, I don't get this error when I take out the upload function.

These are the images:

error on ionic serve
[image: error on ionic serve]

Capture function
[image: Capture function]

Upload function
[image: Upload function]

Comment: Please replace the pictures of code with actual code (as text) and provide the text of the error message. Having these as text makes them searchable, and reusable in other ways.